# When performing a merge-down, Perforce thinks a file has moved that wasn't

Tags: version-control, perforce

Using the Performce Visual Client, I am trying to merge down new content from a parent stream to our feature stream. One of the changes is that a new directory was added, with some content that is similar (but not identical) to what was already in an existing directory. After performing the merge, Perforce incorrectly thinks one of the existing files was actually moved to a location in the newly added directory. The name of this new file is the same, and the name of the new directory is similar to that of the dir that was already there.

It should be noted that the problematic files are not owned by me. It is all code that has never been touched by me or my team.

To clarify:

The original situation:

```
/path/to/file.txt
```

New situation on parent stream:

```
/path/to/file.txt
/path/tofoo/file.txt
```

New situation on my stream after merge:

```
Deleted: /path/to/file.txt
/path/tofoo/file.txt
```

When I look at the second file with "diff against have revision", it shows the deleted file as the "previous" revision, even though in reality it is a new file, which does not have a previous revision.

Anyone have any idea what could cause such behaviour?

Comment: I would look at the filelog output for /path/to/file.txt and see if it was moved or branched. Perforce only uses integration history to figure out how to propagate moves, never content. There could certainly be a bug, but I bet some good money there is some funky integration history involved.

ALso to be clear, did you go through the resolve process after merging down?

Comment: Yep, I did get through the resolve process. This file was not one of the conflicts though. I'll check the filelog tomorrow and see what it says

Comment: I assume you figured this out.  Do you remember what the problem was?